# Expo detached app, generate iOS simulator build for Facebook App Review

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, expo, detach

How can I set publishedURL for developmentURL in “EXBuildConstants.plist” as localhost URL will not work with facebbok app review process?

I am building Expo detached app but I need to generate simulator build for Facebook App review.

Everytime “EXBuildConstants.plist” is updating automatically so my simulator build is not working without running Expo.

Comment: This has been answered in the forum post https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-detached-app-generate-ios-simulator-build-for-facebook-app-review/12235/2

Comment: @EvanBacon thanks. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's answered on [Expo forum](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-detached-app-generate-ios-simulator-build-for-facebook-app-review/12235)

Change in xcode, go to `Product-> Scheme->edit Scheme` and change build configuration to `Release`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Non-Ejected Method**

If you'd like to avoid ejecting an Expo "managed" project, you can follow [these directions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps#5-test-it-on-your-device-or) in order to generate the Simulator build (*.app).

The steps from the link are as follows:

1. Build your expo project with the simulator flag by running `expo build:ios -t simulator`.
2. Download the tarball with the link given upon completion when running `expo build:status`.
3. Unpack the tar.gz by running `tar -xvzf your-app.tar.gz`. This will generate the Simulator build file.

Please note the link for the compressed file will be the last thing logged to your terminal when building your app.

After that, you would just zip the simulator build as mention [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced):

The steps for zipping the build file are as follows:

1. Run `` ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t src/*.app | head -n 1` destination/build.zip ``, where `src/*.app` is the path the the simulator build file, and `destination/build.zip` is the destination.

Comment: Please provide the essentional information in your answer as the link might go out of date.